# Create data bins in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I've got the following task: there are two outputs from DAQ, namely speed and the raw data acquired along with this speed. I'd like to use speed as a parameter to define certain number of bins, and fit the raw data which corresponds to the speed into the specific bin. I am not sure how to do this in LabVIEW - because when I check the histogram function, it seems that it only requires one input (1D array of values). 
Many thanks, any help is much appreciated. Aileen

Answer (score 1):

The [Histogram](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/gmath/histogram_discrete/) VI takes an array of data and the number of bins you want, and determines the boundaries of the bins automatically. It sounds like that's the one you're looking at.

The [General Histogram](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/gmath/general_histogram_vi/) VI allows you to specify the bins yourself. If you can't find it, perhaps you only have the LabVIEW Base Package development system, as it's only present in the Full Development System and above.

If you don't have General Histogram and you need to create a histogram using your own bin boundaries, it wouldn't be too hard to create. Without writing the code for you, you could do something like:

- Create a 1D array containing your bin boundaries in ascending order.
- Use a For loop to index through the array of bin boundaries
- In the loop, use (e.g.) `>`, `<=`, and `And` functions to get a Boolean array which contains True for each value in the data array that should be in the current bin
- Use [Boolean to (0,1)](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/glang/boolean_to_0_1/) and [Add Array Elements](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361N-01/glang/add_array_elements/) to count the number of True values.

If any of that's unclear, please edit your question with more details and perhaps an example of some input data and what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of nekomatic's description.

The first SubVi just creates the 1D array containing your bin boundaries.
**X_in** and **Y_in** are the independent and dependent input datasets. Both have to be of equal length but must not be sorted. In the inner For loop it will be checked if **X_in** fits into the current bin. If so, X_in and the corresponding Y_in value are stored in a temporary arrays which are averaged afterwards.
[image: Binning of 2D array corresponding to first dimension]
Maybe it is not the most efficient code but at least it seems to be not slower than the General Histogram VI